# PHP // MYSQL // JAVASCRIPT needed for a native iOS online app?

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

I'm thinking of developing an app where you can look at each other's profiles (basically a Job-Finding Application) and I would like to know if you needed any knowledge of PHP, MYSQL for the databases and would you need any knowledge of Javascript to develop the application.

I'm currently looking at Google Firebase and also didn't know if that required any PHP knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the Firebase SDKs that you would use in your client app do not require any programming language knowledge other than what's required for your client platform.  If you want to write entirely in swift, that's fine.

The only exception is Cloud Functions, which requires that you learn JavaScript to run on the backend.

Comment: Would I need to learn MySQL too?

Comment: Firebase doesn't offer anything related to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps are built in Swift or C#, typically not javascript and never php.

You can build a PWA (progressive web app) that acts like an ios app using javascript Libraries such as react.

However, MySQL is a database that can be used with any number of applications and programming languages, so you should probably learn that.

My guess is that if you are asking this question, you probably should consult the Apple developer documentation before asking on this form.

Comment: That would be ObjC, not C#.

Comment: Can you not do iOS development with C# through xamarin?

Comment: That would be utilizing a third party library but yes. I was more speaking to the actual language itself; Swift or ObjC being the two main coding languages for iOS/macOS.